# Recursive calls with match for operation search on binary tree

Tags: functional-programming, ocaml

I have come across a solution to the problem of searching a value in the binary tree and returning the node of that residing value. The time complexity is thus expected to be O(n).

This is my solution to the problem:

```
let rec search x tree = 
  match tree with 
  | Empty -> Empty
  | Node (root, left, right) when x = root -> tree
  | Node (_, left, right) ->
    match left with
    | Empty -> search x right
    | t -> search x t
```

and this is the solution I found, but I think mine is more efficient and readable:

```
let rec search x t =
  match t with
  | Empty -> Empty
  | Node(v, l, r) ->
    if v = x then t
    else 
      match search x l with
      | Empty -> search x r
      | t' -> t'
```

Is my solution better or am I missing something?

For reference, the definition of the `tree` type:

```
type 'a tree = 
  | Empty
  | Node of 'a * 'a tree * 'a tree
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are not equivalent in functionality.

Your function only searches the right branch if the left branch is itself `Empty`, and not if the result of *searching* that branch is `Empty`.

Consider:

```
# let leaf v = Node (v, Empty, Empty) in
  search 4 @@ Node (2, leaf 1, leaf 4);;
- : int tree = Empty
```

You might have meant:

```
let rec search x tree = 
  match tree with 
  | Empty -> Empty
  | Node (root, _, _) when x = root -> tree
  | Node (_, left, right) ->
    match search x left with
    | Empty -> search x right
    | t -> t
```

Now:

```
# let leaf v = Node (v, Empty, Empty) in
  search 4 @@ Node (2, leaf 1, leaf 4);;
- : int tree = Node (4, Empty, Empty)
```

An additional thought is that you may want to create a `search_opt` function which returns an `option` type, where `None` indicates that no match was found.

```
let rec search_opt x = 
  function 
  | Empty -> None
  | Node (root, _, _) as tree when x = root -> Some tree
  | Node (_, left, right) ->
    match search_opt x left with
    | None -> search_opt x right
    | t -> t
```

Let's say we have a tree: `let t = Node (2, Node (5, Node (7, leaf 1, leaf 6), leaf 10), Node (8, leaf 3, leaf 4)`.

```
          ------2------
         /             \
     ---5---         ---8---
    /       \       /       \
  -7-       10     3         4
 /   \
1     6
```

If I evaluate `search_opt 3 t`, then that breaks down something like:

```
search_opt 3 t
  search_opt 3 (Node (5, Node (7, leaf 1, leaf 6), leaf 10))
    search_opt 3 (Node (7, leaf 1, leaf 6))
      search_opt 3 (Node (1, Empty, Empty))
        search_opt 3 Empty -> None
        search_opt 3 Empty -> None
    search_opt 3 (Node (10, Empty, Empty))
      search_opt 3 Empty -> None
      search_opt 3 Empty -> None
  search_opt 3 (Node (8, leaf 3, leaf 4))
    search_opt 3 (Node (3, Empty, Empty)) -> Some (Node (3, Empty, Empty))
```

Comment: Thanks, can you give an example how your code will run? I don't get how recursion will work in your code.

Comment: Thanks again, I got what you mean. Though this line `| t -> t` will never be used, but we added it to complete the matching right?

Comment: Why do you think it will never be used?

Comment: Because we will always return `None` and thus `search_opt x left` will never have a value other than `None` from recursive call returns

Comment: Except that eventually it will return `Some ...`

Comment: Oh yeah, sorry I was meaning in case we didn't find `x`